# Javascript - Check filetype(s) on "dragenter"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to allow jpg files only, and when you dragenter/dragover, if at least one file being dragged over isn't a jpg then I want to show the error message, otherwise just show active dropzone. I can't get the proper syntax for checking for jpg files only...I just keep getting my error message triggered even when the file time is a jpg (Whatever I'm doing wrong is also causing some buggy behavior with the dropzone, so if you want to actually drop a jpg file into it, you have to release quickly.)

Here's what I have (same code for dragover)

```
   container.addEventListener(
    "dragover",
    (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    const img = Array.from(e.dataTransfer.items).find(e => e.type.match('image/jpeg'))
    if (img) container.classList.add("active");
    else {} error.innerHTML = HTML hidden in snippet for readability;
    error.classList.remove("hideit");
    },
     false
   );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z7fd4erq/

Answer (score 0):

`dataTransfer.item` will not give you the file type and `dataTransfer.files` is only accessible in the `drop` event so you can only check the file type in the `drop` event for security reasons.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/files